# cycles render not showing changes in render viewport, only materials viewport

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, node-editor

hello i'm working in cycles blender and the changes i made to my eyebrows in node show in the material viewport but not the render viewport, screens below. any suggestions? i don't think i unwrapped anything, is this causing the issue? i'm new to cycles, thank you in advance.

[image]

[image]

EDIT:::

i fixed it somewhat, but do you notice the lightening of the skin color around the eyebrow? anyone know how to fix this part?
[image]

Comment: about the eyebrow, I'm not sure about your node organization, maybe plug the Image Texture and the Transparent shader into a Mix shader, and use the alpha of the Image Texture as the factor of the shader?

Comment: thanks moonboots this worked. tell me how i can upvote you and i shall!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plug the Image Texture and the Transparent shader into a Mix shader, and use the alpha of the Image Texture as the factor of the Mix shader.

Answer (score 0):

solved, had to add in the mix shader like moonboots said [image]